# NPM Install Fails Via Squid Proxy With UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

Tags: npm, openssl, reverse-proxy, squid

we have a Squid proxy with SSL in place, using a self signed certifcate along with a ca-bundle.cert. Only recently NPM installs started to fail when trying to install

npm --registry https://registry.npmjs.org  \
--proxy http://localhost:10080 --https-proxy http://localhost:10443 \
--ddd install express

Producing error -

```
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/express failed, 
reason: unable to verify the first certificate
```

Squid is running inside a Docker, and it's log shows

```
NONE/200 0 CONNECT registry.npmjs.org:443 - HIER_DIRECT
```

Any ideas or pointers would be much appreciated.

## First reply response

I added "dns_v4_first on" to the squid.conf and now the NPM error message is

```
npm verb node v8.9.3
npm verb npm  v5.5.1
npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! errno SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/express failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

## Additional info

What I've discovered is unusual behaviour around NPM accepting proxy settings. When the proxy is set inline as seen below it returns a HTTP 503.

```
npm cache clear --force && rm -rf node_modules/

npm --strict-ssl=false --registry https://registry.npmjs.org 
--proxy http://example-proxy.net:3339 --https-proxy http://example-proxy.net:3339 
--ddd install express
```

When ONLY the proxy is set and not https-proxy it works!

```
npm cache clear --force && rm -rf node_modules/

npm --strict-ssl=false --registry https://registry.npmjs.org 
--proxy http://example-proxy.net:3339  
--ddd install express
```

When the proxy is set in the shell and and not via the npm command, it works!

```
export http_proxy=http://example-proxy.net:3339 
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://example-proxy.net:3339 
export https_proxy=http://example-proxy.net:3339 
export HTTP_PROXY=http://example-proxy.net:3339

npm cache clear --force && rm -rf node_modules/

npm --strict-ssl=false --registry https://registry.npmjs.org 
--ddd install express
```

So why does the npm command return a HTTP 503 when both proxy and https-proxy are set?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like squid is trying to connect via IPv6 on a host with only IPv4:

```
connect(14, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(443), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2400:cb00:2048:1::6810:1b23", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = -1 ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
read(14, 0x7ffe450e1040, 65535)         = -1 ENOTCONN (Transport endpoint is not connected)
```

Adding this option to squid.conf fixes it:

```
dns_v4_first on
```